# Execute Custom Index before Magento Indexes - Re-order Indexing

Tags: magento2, indexing

I have created a custom module which contains indexing logic. The indexing is working and my data is being indexed.

But the problem is that my custom indexes always executes after Magento's default indexes have finished execution. I want to run my index before Magento's default indexes.

I have checked default Magento's indexes and found that there is no `sort_order` attribute or anything like that for indexes in its configuration files. I have also found that the indexes are not being executed in the order it is stored in database table.

I think it is executed based on module execution/load. Is there any way I can re-order indexes to execute my indexes first and then default Magento's indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to get a work around for my problem. I did it with a plugin as below.
In my **di.xml** file I added below code.

```
<type name="Magento\Indexer\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="reOrderIndexes" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\Indexer\Config" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

And then added a new plugin file **/app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Indexer/Config.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Indexer;

class Config
{
    const MY_INDEXER_ID = "my_indexer_id";
    /**
     * Get indexers list
     *
     * @return array[]
     */
    public function afterGetIndexers(\Magento\Indexer\Model\Config $subject, $result)
    {
        $indexers = $result;
        foreach ($indexers as $key => $indexer) {
            if($key == self::MY_INDEXER_ID){
                $temp = array($key => $indexers[$key]);
                unset($indexers[$key]);
                $indexers = $temp + $indexers;
            }
        }
        return $indexers;
    }
}
```

This will reorder indexer array and put my custom indexer at first place in execution queue.